# Angular Route Displays Raw JSON on Browser Refresh

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I am building a MEAN stack app.  I've set up a proxy config for development.  I am successfully calling an API from Angular/Node, but when I refresh the browser, the Angular route displays my raw JSON data like this:

[image]

There aren't much specifics on StackOverflow about this particular problem.  I'm 99% certain it's a problem with how I've set up my Angular and Node routing, but I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

## proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

## My Angular route

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent },
    { path: 'homeaway/search', component: ResultsComponent }
];
```

## Angular service method

```
  searchListings(trip) {
    console.log("search listing", trip)

    //Grab all of the params from the trip argument and append them to params variable
    let params = new HttpParams()
    Object.keys(trip).forEach(function (key) {
     params = params.append(key, trip[key]);
    });

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    const options = {
      headers: headers,
      params: params
    }

    return this.http.get(`/homeaway/search`, options) <-- MY GET CALL
    .pipe(
      map((res: Response) => res),
      catchError(error => throwError(error.message || error))
      )

  }
```

## Node server info

```
var homeAwayRouter = require('./routes/homeaway');
app.use('/homeaway', homeAwayRouter)
```

## My Node route

```
router.get('/search', (req,res,next)  => {

    let params = {
      availabilityStart: req.query.availabilityStart,
      availabilityEnd: req.query.availabilityEnd,
      minSleeps: req.query.minSleeps,
      centerPointLatitude: req.query.centerPointLatitude,
      centerPointLongitude: req.query.centerPointLongitude,
      distanceInKm: req.query.distanceInKm
    }

    axios.get(searchURL, options, params)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Successful HomeAway search in server /search', response);
        res.send(response.data); //Send data
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })

  });
```

## Results component

**Where the service method is called**

```
ngOnInit() {

    //Query params-based search on page init
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
         this.homeAwayService.searchListings(params).subscribe((res) => {
             this.searchResults = res
             console.log("response in activatedRoute in results", this.searchResults)
         });
  })

}
```

## package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run serve-api\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "serve": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "serve-api": "nodemon server/app.js --watch server",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

*Some things I've tried:*

- Change Angular route URL to just match 'homeaway' or 'search'
- Change the proxy.config url to match '/homeaway'.  Although I want
  the path to be usable for any backend url request I need to make.

All of these result in 404 errors.

So just to clarify:  I get the API data successfully and my URL works initially.  A page refresh displays the raw JSON instead of my Angular/HTML.

I'm fairly new to MEAN stack routing, so I would love some help figuring this out and learning *why* something like this would be happening.  Thanks for taking a look.

EDIT:  I imagine this might be caused because my Angular and Node routes ('/homeaway/search') match each other, but I'm not sure why that would cause a problem.  When I've attempted to change the node or Angular route so that they don't match, I get a 404.

Comment: Have you built and deployed the angular app on your node server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've done a build for your angular app, you might need to change the routing in one of your apps. What may be happening here is that when you change routes in UI, angular takes care of it. It hits the API and gets you the `json` response your application expects. But when you hit a refresh on your browser, your node server gets the full url `localhost:3000/search` and returns the `json` response, instead of an returning a HTML or js file and the same json is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I think that is what's happening, but how would I change the routing to address the problem without incurring a 404?  Edit:  Adding my package.json above.  My npm start creates the proxy and compiles my Angular app.

Comment: just change the get/post url that your angular app is calling. Make changes in both the app and the server.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you be more specific about what should be modified?  I've added the ngOnInit of my results component, where the service method is called.  I'm curious whether Angular can't route because of the query params.

Comment: Change the api on server side as well as URL in angular. In your service method replace `this.http.get(`/homeaway/search`, options)` with `this.http.get(`/homeaway/search-something`, options)` and on the server-side reaplce `router.get('/search', (req,res,next)  => {` with `router.get('/search-something', (req,res,next)  => {`

Comment: It works, thank you!  I then started getting a 404 on page refresh after the change and implemented HashLocationStrategy, and that resolved the 404.  Thanks for your help